# Multiple conditions in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a htaccess file which grabs pretty much anything after the / sign and gives it to my index.php?i. This works perfectly but I want to take it one step closer and have the same htaccess use conditions. 
Currently this is the navigation method mysite.com/stuff/cat
the htaccess simply grabs the string stuff/cat and my PHP can then load up contents about it. But what I want to do is: when the navigation is mysite.com/stuff/cat/**images** I want the htaccess to redirect to another file rather than my index.php. Is it possible to add some kind of If statement or condition in htaccess? (if string contains '**images**' redirect to gallery.php?i=data)

here is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\s'-()]+)$ index.php?i=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following (place it under your `RewriteOptions`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_\s'-()]+)/images$ gallery.php?i=$1 [L]
```

I would recommend using the `L` flag (as above) in your other rule too.

Comment: Thank you so much! exactly what I wanted